# Angular 2 animation first init

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an component animation here:

```
animations:  [
    trigger('profilemenuState', [
        state('deselected', style({
            width: '8.3%'
        })),
        state('selected', style({
            width: '30%'
        })),
        transition('deselected => selected', animate('500ms ease-in')),
        transition('selected => deselected', animate('500ms ease-out'))
    ])
]
```

and html template like:

```
<div [@profilemenuState]="state"
     (@profilemenuState.done)="test()">
</div>
```

The question is why event `done` is firing in initial loading, before `state` will be toggled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is fired every time the profileState-trigger has changed to one of its states. If your `state` variable contains `"deselected"` as initial state, `(done)` is fired because of the transition from `void => deselected`.

If you want to differentiate between the different states within the `test()` method you can change it to `test($event)` and you get an argument of type `AnimationTransitionEvent` injected into the method. There you get some information about the current state.

e.g.

```
test(event: AnimationTransitionEvent) {
    console.log(event.toState);
}
```

Hope this helps!